# Can someone help me my google dev console is saying .getcontext is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can anyone help me my dev console keeps saying Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function.
The code in question is

```
`var canvas = document.createElement
var c = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
document.body.append.Child(canvas);`
```

Thanks in advance,
Dartfrog

Answer (score 0):

You should point out what element your are creating (`var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');`). And `appendChild` should be in one word.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
<script>
const CANVAS_WIDTH = 1024;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 768;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
canvas.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
canvas.style.background = "red";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of only `document.createElement` you should use `document.createElement('canvas')`

for more see this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_canvas.asp